# How to move legend box all the way to the left of the plot and align with titles and subtitles in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data and picture setup as below

```
df <- data_frame(group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 20),
       y = c(sample(1:90, 20, replace = TRUE),
             sample(1:30, 20, replace = TRUE)),
       x = rep(1:20, 2)
       )
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group))+
   geom_line()+
   labs(x = "", y = "", title = "Comparison", 
     subtitle = "Unit (thousand)", 
     caption = "Source: Kaggle")+
   theme(legend.title = element_blank(), 
     legend.position = "top", 
     legend.justification='left',
     legend.box = "horizontal",
     legend.key = element_blank(),
     legend.box.margin = margin(0,0,0,0,"cm"),
     plot.title.position = "plot",
     plot.caption.position =  "plot",
     plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

and generate the graph here:

[image]

How to move legend box all the way to the left of the plot and align with titles and subtitles? Also have to taken into account that there's a margin in legend.key.

Also appreciated it if you can let me know how to reduce the space around legend as well. Thanks!

Comment: It might be helpful to mock up with paint or preview exactly where you want the legend.

Comment: Read this part on legends from the [R Cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach with specifying `legend.position` manually, as well as adding `\n` to the subtitle to create extra space. You'll also need `legend.direction = "horizontal"` and `legend.margin = margin(0)`:

Note you'll probably have to fiddle with the numbers in `legend.position` as it will be slightly different for every plotting device.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group))+
   geom_line()+
   labs(x = "", y = "", title = "Comparison", 
     subtitle = "Unit (thousand)\n", 
     caption = "Source: Kaggle")+
   theme(legend.title = element_blank(), 
     legend.position = c(-0.065,1.05), 
     legend.justification='left',
     legend.box = "horizontal",
     legend.margin = margin(0),
     legend.key = element_blank(),
     legend.direction = "horizontal",
     plot.title.position = "plot",
     plot.caption.position =  "plot",
     plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to align the tick marks to titles, subtitles and captions as well? Been trying a few options but haven't worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, I thought you want the legend next to the title / subtitle. With the approach of changing plot margins you gain some flexibility. You can use margins to widen the plot area and to position the legend.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 20),
                 y = c(sample(1:90, 20, replace = TRUE),
                       sample(1:30, 20, replace = TRUE)),
                 x = rep(1:20, 2)
)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group))+
  geom_line()+
  labs(x = "", y = "", title = "Comparison", 
       subtitle = "Unit (thousand)", 
       caption = "Source: Kaggle")+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = "top", 
        legend.justification='left',
        legend.box = "horizontal",
        legend.key = element_blank(),
        legend.box.margin = margin(-1,0,0,-2,"cm"),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 2), "cm"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.2),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.2),
        plot.caption.position =  "plot",
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0)
        )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>